# SQLのIN句で指定した値を全て含むレコードを抽出する方法を教えてください。

Tags: sql

例

```
A1｜A2

---------

001|ABCCBA

002|BBBCCC

003|AAACCC
```

```
SELECT *

FROM テーブル

WHERE A2 IN('AA','CC')
```

というふうにしたとき`AA`と`CC`を同時にA2に含んでいる`003``だけを取得したいです。

Comment: データベースが何かぐらいは書けませんか？　SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? PostgreSQL? Access? SQLite? その他?

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。MySQLになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

※ MySQL v5.7 で確認しています。

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f6mdmhuHqSAfY6zUB9KF54/0)

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (A1 VARCHAR(10), A2 VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO A VALUES
   ('001', 'ABCCBA'), ('002', 'BBBCCCC'), ('003', 'AAACCCC');

SELECT * FROM A WHERE A2 LIKE '%AA%' AND A2 LIKE '%CC%';
```

| A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- |
| 003 | AAACCCC |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *

FROM テーブル

WHERE A2 LIKE "%AA%CC%"
```

REとかwildcardを使ってもいいです

実行して見てください

参考リンクhttps://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_wildcards.asp